# Testing IPv6 from iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos

I need to test IPv6 connection from iPhone app. I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16) and everything is running alright. But [testing](http://test-ipv6.com) for IPv6 fails with "No IPv6 address detected".

One thing I am not clear about is: The doc says that I should use the NAT64 Network - I suppose that just means connecting to the name of the wi-fi network created?

Any help or have you had any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per apple [compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16) we are not connecting to IPv6 endpoint, which is an IPv6 network that continues to provide access to IPv4 content through translation (DNS64/NAT64). Simply, provider network is IPv4 and translating it to IPv6 network as per apple compliance.if you have actual IPv6 then [testing](http://test-ipv6.com/) will succeed.

Comment: Thanks; We are using the domain url and not ipv4 ip address. How would you and should you transform it into ipv6. To me it looks like that is what (DNS64/NAT64) will do for you to be able to actually test this. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: NAT64 is used for translation of IPV4 to IPV6.It is called as dual stacking.as per apple instructions we are locally creating a dual stacking network on Mac which is actually a IPV4 network.Know more about dual stack.Please do googling you can get more details about that.Thanks. http://whatismyipaddress.com/dual-stack